# If $L = \{ a^{2^n} \mid n \ge 0 \} $ is not regular, then why there is a DFA thats accepts its language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Let $L = \{ a^{2^n} \mid n \ge 0 \}$, which is a non-regular language (no proof here). Let $M = (\Sigma,Q,\delta,z_0,F)$ be a DFA with $\Sigma = \{a\}$, $Q = \{z_0\}$, $\delta(z_0, a) = z_0$ and $F = \{z_0\}$. Then the DFA should accept $L$ and $L$ is therefore regular. Why is my approach wrong?

Comment: Your automaton accepts $a^*$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of an automaton accepting a language is that it must

1. accept every string that is in the language;
2. reject every string that is not in the language.

Your automaton does 1. but not 2. – it accepts all strings of $a$s, but it's supposed to reject all the strings whose length is not a power of two.